# how to dump http request variable into file using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am sending a http request along with params like

```
userName = admin
password = admin
```

etc...

I need to capture the request params into a csv file.

Comment: Are you sending these values hard-coded or using some variables ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Beanshell Post Processor to dump the values to csv file like:

- Add [Beanshell Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request
- Put the following code into the Post Processor's "Script" area:

  ```
  import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

  Map params = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments().getArgumentsAsMap();
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  for (String param : params.keySet()) {
      builder.append(param).append(",").append(params.get(param));
      builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
  }        

  FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("/path/to/file.csv"), builder.toString(), true);
  ```

It will produce file with contents like:

```
userName,admin
password,admin
```

Used classes reference:

- `ctx` == [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html)
- [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)
- [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter.

Comment: :Can I also store the content in properties too.

Comment: sure, in Beanshell you can access properties as simple as `props.get("property_name");`